# Elementor call global User variable

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, elementor

I want to create an elementor Formular in WordPress and as action I need to call a webhook.

One parameter of the webhook is the email of the active user account. My idea is to make an invisible field in the formular with the email. My Problem is I dont know how to load the global user variable with elementor formulars. Is that possible ?

Thank you for your help.